# Can I use BIO_puts, BIO_read several times without reconnecting?

Tags: c++, linux, ssl, openssl

Can I use BIO_puts without reconnecting to the server every time I want to use it?

So, here is the full process of connecting to the server with bio (code is simplified to show actual concept):

```
const char * REQUEST_TO_THE_SERVER = "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: stackoverflow.com \r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n";

const char * REQUEST_TO_THE_SERVER_2 = "GET /register HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: stackoverflow.com \r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n";

char BufferForResponce[1000];


    BIO *web;
    SSL * ssl;
    SSL_CTX * ctx;

    OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms();
    ERR_load_BIO_strings();
    ERR_load_crypto_strings();
    SSL_load_error_strings();

    SSL_library_init();
    ctx = SSL_CTX_new(SSLv3_method());
    SSL_CTX_set_options(ctx, flags);
    BIO * web = BIO_new_ssl_connect(ctx);
    BIO_set_conn_hostname(web, "stackoverflow.com:443);
    BIO_get_ssl(web, &ssl);
    SSL_set_cipher_list(ssl, PREFERRED_CIPHERS);
    BIO_new_fp(stdout, BIO_NOCLOSE);
    BIO_do_connect(web);
    BIO_do_handshake(web);

BIO_puts(web, REQUEST_TO_THE_SERVER , sizeof(REQUEST_TO_THE_SERVER)); // it is normal
BIO_read(web, BufferForResponce, sizeof(BufferForResponce)); // it is normal


BIO_puts(web, REQUEST_TO_THE_SERVER_2 , sizeof(REQUEST_TO_THE_SERVER_2)); // it is normal
BIO_read(web, BufferForResponce, sizeof(BufferForResponce)); // FAILS WITH TIMEOUT
```

After this precess I can write to the server with `BIO_puts` but to read from the server I have to do all connection precess again. Other vice `BIO_read` will show `timeout` error

Comment: Please review [MCVE].  And, have you tried it yet?

Comment: I have added code @DOUGLASO.MOEN

Comment: The code pasted doesn't show any calls to `BIO_read` or any way to show an error of any kind, as far as I can tell.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I don't know why, but I can read only once from SSL session, so I have to do another one to write and read again

Comment: Show us the code that tries to read twice and explain how it fails. Also, it would be helpful if you explained what you expected the second read to do. Did you confirm that there was data sent by the server that you hadn't read yet?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Added code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code has two major bugs:

First, you are asking the server to close the connection after sending you its reply:

> GET / HTTP/1.1
>   Host: stackoverflow.com
>   Connection: **close**

The server will not try to read a second request from you or send you a second reply if you ask it to close the connection.

But your second problem is much more serious -- you never actually implemented receiving an HTTP response at all. You're just calling `BIO_read` and assuming that it will somehow figure out what an HTTP response is. You need to write code to receive an HTTP response following the HTTP protocol. Otherwise, you may get a partial response and, worse, on your second call may get some of the first response and some of the second response mixed together.

HTTP version 1.1 is a very complex protocol whose specification has numerous requirements. Attempting to fake it with this kind of toy code is likely to cause more pain than anything else. Why not just stick to HTTP 1.0 and avoid trying to re-use connections, at least until you actually have some HTTP code.